# How to maintain Azure blob storage by automatically delete old blobs?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, storage

So I have an Azure blob storage account with a lot of blobs. Every time a certain pipeline gets executed, it generates an artifact which we store in the Azure storage. Some artifacts we later on deploy to production, but some we don't. I don't want to manually go to the Azure storage and delete the ones that are not deployed.

I would like to give them a sort of tag "production" and then run a script that deletes the blobs that are older than 1 month and do not have the tag "production". This feature however is not build in Azure storage because you can only query based on "==" and not "!=" c.q. "is not equal". Does somebody have ideas?

I would expect a build in functionality where you can filter out the blobs that do not have a specific tag. Based on that outcome delete those that are older than for example 1 month.

Answer (score 0):

simply use a Lifecycle Management policy. See documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/lifecycle-management-policy-configure?tabs=azure-portal

Comment: Nope like I said, the rules you create there only allow you to use "=="

Comment: You are right, Chaouki. I think tagging won't work in the way you want it here. I had a similar task. As a workaround, I had to split the dev and prod files to different containers and then use the blob prefix filter.